# How to store the URL of an image uploaded to Cloudinary.com with Node.js to Mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am uploading the base64 string of an image to Cloudinary with Nodejs and I am getting the URL back from Cloudinary but I am having difficulty trying to store the URL in mongodb.

```
 app.post('/api/amin/create', (req, res) => {
      req.body.adminId= Math.floor(10 + Math.random() * 100);
      var cloudinaryUrl = '';
      cloudinary.uploader.upload(req.body.coverPhotoFile,  function(error, result) {
          {    
               cloudinaryUrl= result.url
               req.body.photoUrl = result.url //sets the value corectly, but does not post to mongodb
          }
     })
       req.body.photoUrl = cloudinaryUrl //sets it to an empty string
 
 })
```

I just need to be able to access the value of cloudinaryUrl outside the upload function. Thanks.

Comment: `return` stops the function. Lines after the `return` in function scope won't be executed.

Comment: it still doesn't work even when the return statement has been removed.

Comment: what is the typeof coverPhotoFile?

Comment: The typeof is string

Answer (score 0):

Add the validation before you go, something like below

```
app.post("/api/amin/create", (req, res) => {
  req.body.adminId = Math.floor(10 + Math.random() * 100);
  req.body.photoUrl = cloudinary.uploader.upload(
    req.body.coverPhotoFile,
    function (error, result) {
      if (error) throw error;
      return result.url;
    }
  );
});
```

if your upload have any issue, it should throw the error

Comment: The function is returning the url. All I want to Know is how I can access the ```cloudinaryUrl ```outside the upload function

Comment: why do you have some extra { } with-in the callback function? remove it and then try it may cause !

Comment: also try this, app.post("/api/amin/create", (req, res) => {
  req.body.adminId = Math.floor(10 + Math.random() * 100);
  req.body.photoUrl = cloudinary.uploader.upload(req.body.coverPhotoFile, function (error, result) {
    if (error) throw error;
    return result.url;
  });
});